# Size Limit On Download From Cloud Storage With App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

tldr: Is there a file size limit to send a file from Cloud Storage to my user's web browser as a download? Am I using the Storage Python API wrong, or do I need to increase the resources set by my App Engine YAML file?

This is just an issue with downloads. Uploads work great up to any file size, using chunking.

---

## The symptoms

I created a file transfer application with App Engine Python 3.7 Standard environment. Users are able to upload files of any size, and that is working well. But users are running into what appears to be a size limit on downloading the resulting file from Cloud Storage.

The largest file I have successfully sent and received through my entire upload/download process was 29 megabytes. Then I sent myself a 55 megabyte file, but when I attempted to receive it as a download, Flask gives me this error:

`Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.`

---

### Application Structure

To create my file transfer application, I used Flask to set up two Services, `internal` and `external`, each with its own Flask routing file, its own webpage/domain, and its own YAML files.

In order to test the application, I visit the `internal` webpage which I created. I use it to upload a file in chunks to my application, which successfully composes the chunks in Cloud Storage. I then log into Google Cloud Platform Console as an admin, and when I look at Cloud Storage, it will show me the 55 megabyte file which I uploaded. It will allow me to download it directly through the Cloud Platform Console, and the file is good.

(Up to that point of the process, this even worked for a 1.5 gigabyte file.)

Then I go to my `external` webpage as a non-admin user. I use the form to attempt to receive that same file as a download. I get the above error. However, this whole process encounters no errors for my 29 megabyte test file, or smaller.

Stacktrace Debugger logs for this service reveal:

`logMessage:  "The process handling this request unexpectedly died. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 203)"`

---

### Possible solutions

I added the following lines to my `external` service YAML file:

`resources: 
  memory_gb: 100
  disk_size_gb: 100`

The error remained the same. Apparently this is not a limit of system resources?

Perhaps I'm misusing the Python API for Cloud Storage. I'm importing `storage` from `google.cloud`. Here is where my application responds to the user's POST request by sending the user the file they requested:

```
@app.route('/download', methods=['POST'])
def provide_file():
    return external_download()
```

This part is in `external_download`:

```
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(current_app.cloud_storage_bucket)
    bucket_filename = request.form['filename']
    blob = bucket.blob(bucket_filename)

    return send_file(io.BytesIO(blob.download_as_string()),
                     mimetype="application/octet-stream",
                     as_attachment=True,
                     attachment_filename=filename)
```

Do I need to implement chunking for downloads, not just uploads?

Comment: I don't mean to sidestep your question, but consider offloading the download/upload to GCS so that your application doesn't have to spend resources on the transfer. If you use GCS Signed URLs you can have frontend clients directly upload/download from GCS and still monitor authorization.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t recommend to use [Flask's `send_file()` method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file)  for managing large files transfer, Flask file handling methods were intended for use by developers or API's, to exchange system messages mostly, like logs, cookies and other light objects.

Besides, the [`download_as_string()`](https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.download_as_string) method might indeed conceal a buffer limitation, I did reproduce your scenario and got the same error message with files larger than 30mb, however I couldn’t find more information about such constraint. It might be intentional, induced by the method’s purpose (download content as string, not fitted for large objects).

Proven ways to handle file transfer efficiently with Cloud Storage and Python:

- Use methods of the [Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) directly, to [download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-code_sample) and [upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) objects without using Flask. As @FridayPush mentioned, it will offload your application, and you can control access with [Signed URL’s](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).
- Use the [Blobstore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/), a straightforward, lightweight, and simple solution to handle file transfer, fully integrated with GCS buckets and intended for this type of situation.
- Use the [built-in Python Requests module](http://masnun.com/2016/09/18/python-using-the-requests-module-to-download-large-files-efficiently.html), requires to create your own handlers to communicate with GCS.